# Streaming files from a remote server to a asp.net mvc client

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, html5-video

I am trying to stream secure content located on server A via a secure application located on server B to a web client in an mvc application.

Basically, it looks like I have to authenticate with server A in my app and stream chunks of the file from server to server to client to prevent the overhead of downloading a temp copy in full prior to downloading. (**I do not want to write the file to server B's disk**)

In this case the content is comprised of video file being viewed in an html5 video element and the files are coming from a cdn.

Does anyone know of any shortcuts to get me started?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I was able to use query string authorization while creating the video url to the remote server, so no need for a file proxy.